# Android 1dp stroke drawable cannot be drawn in a 1dp height view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have a regular XML stroke drawable like so:

```xml
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#B2B2B2"
        android:dashWidth="4dp"
        android:dashGap="8dp" />
</shape>
```

And a view (or an image view) that uses the drawable as its background.
When I set the height of that view to `1.5dp` or bigger, the line will render but `1dp` will not render the line.

A `2dp` height view will draw the line at the center, making it position in the middle of other view layouts.

I tried making the height `3dp` and use bottom paddings, but it won't work.

What is going on and is there any solution for this?

Comment: @Mr.AF Dash width is for the stroke width. The `width` on stroke is in fact the height of the stroke.

Comment: @Mr.AF Why? What effect will it have besides not displaying properly across devices?